# How to check the same condition on multiple variables and return a matching message for each one?

Tags: python

Is there an any simple way to make the below code more simple in Python?

```
if a is None:
   return "Error - a has to be provided"
          
if b is None: 
   return "Error - b has to be provided"

if c is None: 
   return "Error - c has to be provided"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mapping between variable name and its matching object (just to avoid hacky uses of `globals` and such) and then loop over the variables:

```
variables = {'a': a,
             'b': b,
             'c': c}

for var_name, var in variables.items():
    if var is None:
        return f"Error - {var_name} has to be provided"
```